# how can i delete application storage directory instance/data when uninstalling any air application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, air

how can i delete storage directory instances or folder while uninstalling any air application. In my application when i first time run my application, application copy some data from application directory to application storage directory. now i want to delete all data and application directory folder also while uninstalling application.

I am doing that because when i launch any update then application is accessing old data which conflict with my application new features.

So how can i achieve it. please guide

Comment: Couldn't you just add code to the section that copies over the data the first time to delete any old content first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following references might help:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3459801

A free open-source tool to get this done:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

The essense of the discussion is that you cannot use an AIR uninstaller to achieve what you are trying to do.Hence a third-party think wrapper.

Comment: i think, i should write custom code for achieving that functionality.

Comment: Even if you do write custom code, the issue is that when the user goes to the "Uninstall" menu, the AIR does not tell your code that the program is being uninstalled.But incase you do find a way to get that done, let us know that would be great.